# How to get absolute path with Vert.x?

Tags: vert.x

How can I get the absolute path of a file without hardcoding the path in a String?

So basically I'm asking for vert.x's version of PHP's `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. Does anybody know?

**UPDATE**
I have the following directory structure:

```
| app.coffee
| Views
  -| foo.html
```

app.coffee:

```
vertx = require('vertx')
rm    = new vertx.RouteMatcher()

rm.get '/', (req) ->
    req.response.sendFile "Views/foo.html"

vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(rm).listen(8080)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the execution directory of the application. To get the execution directory you can just look up the system property 'user.dir' like so:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

So for instance when I serve static files in vertx for testing I use this:

```
val staticFilePath = container.config().getString("static_files", System.getProperty("user.dir"));
  server.requestHandler(
  {
    request: HttpServerRequest => {
      request.response().sendFile(staticFilePath + "/something.css")
    }
  }
```

If you are still not getting the desired result just print out the user.dir property to see where you are trying to serve files from.

References:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just type in a relative path, it will refer to the working directory you launched the vertx command into.

Look at this simple example:

```
$ ls
index.html  verticle.scala
```

As you can see, I have a verticle and  a static file in my (unspecified!) directory.

```
$ cat index.html
Hello!

$ cat verticle.scala
vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler({ req: HttpServerRequest =>
    req.response().sendFile("index.html") // <-- relative path!
}).listen(8080)
```

Now I just run it from here

```
$ vertx run verticle.scala
Compiling verticle.scala as Scala script
Starting verticle.scala
Succeeded in deploying verticle
```

And it just works, no need at all to specify constants like in PHP :)

```
$ curl localhost:8080
Hello!
```

Enjoy!

Comment: That's what I tried, but a relative path doesn't seem to work for me. Or I'm just doing it wrong. Check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're trying to do

```
curl http://localhost:8080/foo.html
```

That can't work because your route matcher is configured to match / and respond with the contents of foo.html.

The right test case should be instead:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/
```

and the expected result should be

```
Hello!
```

Route matcher is not is the wrong tool for serving static files. If you intend to do that, refer to the [web server module](https://github.com/vert-x/mod-web-server.)

**UPDATE**

Mate, this thing works for me in coffeescript too. What Vert.x version are you using?

```
$ vertx version
2.1 (built 2014-05-27 12:39:02)
$ cat app.coffee
vertx = require('vertx')
rm    = new vertx.RouteMatcher()

rm.get '/', (req) ->
    req.response.sendFile "Views/foo.html"

vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(rm).listen(8080)
$ vertx run app.coffee &
[1] 27731
$ Succeeded in deploying verticle

$ curl localhost:8080
ciao
$ cat Views/foo.html
ciao
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, again. But I know how the routeMatcher works. When I do `curl -i http://localhost:8080/` I get a 404: `Resource not found`. I've read the docs, I've tried the examples, but relative paths don't seem to work for me. However when I provide an absolute path it _does_ work. That's why I'd like to know how to get the path of the current file, to prevent hardcoding.

Comment: Can you replicate this with the Javascript translated version of your program?